# Подскажите, как подключить Google Play Game Services к Android-приложению на QT

Tags: android, c++, qt, google-play-services

Подскажите, как подключить Google Play Game Services к Android-приложению на QT

Comment: https://github.com/kafeg/adctl не?

Comment: Буду смотреть)Благодарю

Comment: https://github.com/kafeg/adctl - че то там сложно слишком, не получается пока разобраться. Есть попроще?